# Matlab: nest fzero in fminsearch

Tags: matlab, optimization, fminsearch

I am trying to minimize with respect to a variable "y" a function that contains a parameter which must be calculated as a solution of an equality that contains "y" as well (say, y=-3; in my complete problem it is an equation with no analytic closed form solution, so I really need fzero).
Because of this, I include the fzero function in the argument of fminsearch:

```
 fminsearch( @(y) 10*fzero(@(y) y+3, 0)) ;
```

I get the error:

```
Error using fminsearch (line 85)
The input to FMINSEARCH should be either a structure with 
valid fields or consist of at least two arguments.
```

I obviously get the same error with: 
    f = fzero(@(y) y+3, 0);
    fminsearch(@(y) 10*f);

Apparently the problem is that I cannot "nest" a fzero inside fminsearch.
Any idea about how to turn around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error message you got and look at the documentation of [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) you'll see that you need to call it with **two** input arguments. You call it with only one.

```
fminsearch( @(y) 10*fzero(@(x) x+3, 0), 0 )
```

Comment: Oh, I was hasty...time to take a break if I did not see that. Thank you.